# Best way to pass back error info from a model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, return

I have a service which is called from my controller to upload images. This works well, but when criteria is not met, it currently returns 'null' which is not helpful or elegant. Current code is:

```
    public async Task<string> UploadPropertyImageAsync(HttpPostedFileBase imageToUpload)
    {
        string imageFullPath = null;
        if (imageToUpload == null || imageToUpload.ContentLength == 0 || imageToUpload.ContentLength >= 8388608)
        {
            return null;
        }

        WebImage img = new WebImage(imageToUpload.InputStream);
        if (img.Width < 1000)
        {
            return null;
        }    

        try
        {
            //Do Something
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log something
        }
        return imageFullPath;
    }
}
```

I have tried passing ViewBag and TempData back, but neither seems to be valid code? How can I write an error message string and pass it back to a view?

*Adding controller method*

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Upload([Bind(Include = "ID,Caption")] HttpPostedFileBase photo, PropertyImage image, int propertyId)
    {
        var imageUrl = await imageService.UploadPropertyImageAsync(photo);
        var imageGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        image.Original_URL = imageUrl.ToString();
        image.PropertyID = propertyId;
        image.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        image.ID = imageGuid;
        image.Status = true;
        db.PropertyImage.Add(image);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action should return  `Task<ActionResult>` if it is an MVC application or `Task<IHttpActionResult>` if it was a web API.

In your code, if the criteria is not met, then return a Bad Request, using the return `BadRequest()` helper method which exist in both `Controller` and `ApiController` classes.
You can also include additional information in the request body.

So, your code should be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Upload([Bind(Include = "ID,Caption")] HttpPostedFileBase photo, PropertyImage image, int propertyId)
    {
        var imageUrl = await imageService.UploadPropertyImageAsync(photo);
        if(imageUrl == null)  
           return BadRequest();
        else
        {
         var imageGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
         image.Original_URL = imageUrl.ToString();
         image.PropertyID = propertyId;
         image.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
         image.ID = imageGuid;
         image.Status = true;
         db.PropertyImage.Add(image);
         await db.SaveChangesAsync();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }


   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadPropertyImageAsync(HttpPostedFileBase imageToUpload)
    {
        string imageFullPath = null;
        if (imageToUpload == null || imageToUpload.ContentLength == 0 || imageToUpload.ContentLength >= 8388608)
        {
            return null;
        }

        WebImage img = new WebImage(imageToUpload.InputStream);
        if (img.Width < 1000)
        {
            return null;
        }    

        try
        {
            //Do Something
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log something
        }
        return  imageFullPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: But this code doesn't exist in the controller, it is called 'from' the controller. So returning BadRequest() isn't possible right?

Comment: What do you mean it is called from the controller? do you mean this is a helper method and is called from the controller action or what?

Comment: I have added controller code to my original question

Comment: In this case, you will leave the upload method as is to return null and check the return in the action, if it is null, you will return `BadRequest`, I have edited the answer

Comment: That's now doing exactly what i wanted it to do. Thank you very much for your assistance

Comment: Great, happy that I could help

Answer (score 0):

Your task is returning a string!

So you could do something like

```
if (imageToUpload == null || imageToUpload.ContentLength == 0 || imageToUpload.ContentLength >= 8388608)
{
            return "MY_ERROR_STRING";
}
```

Not the best way at all

My advice would be to return an simple object

```
public class ResultObj(){
  public bool Success {get;set;};
  public string Result {get;set;};
}
```

then test for success, if true the result is the path, if false, its your error message. so your code would look like

```
 public async Task<ResultObj> UploadPropertyImageAsync(HttpPostedFileBase imageToUpload)
    {
        ResultObj result = null;
        if (imageToUpload == null || imageToUpload.ContentLength == 0 || imageToUpload.ContentLength >= 8388608)
        {
            result.Success= False;
            result.Result = "We have error" ;
            return result;
        }

        WebImage img = new WebImage(imageToUpload.InputStream);
        if (img.Width < 1000)
        {
            result.Success= False;
            result.Result = "We have a different error" ;
            return result;
        }    

        try
        {
            //Do Something
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log something
        }
        result.Success= true;
        result.Result = imageFullPath;
        return result;
    }
```